# How to configure /etc/hosts to test local Docker setup

Tags: nginx, docker, hosts

I'm trying to develop a web app locally using native Docker for OS X (beta) to handle the entire environment.

In order to fake the production DNS configuration (to test Nginx setup) I have edited the host file (at /private/etc/hosts):

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

# Added by me
0.0.0.0         www.mydomain.com
```

The Nginx config file is tested and is working on production server.

**Expected behaviour:**
When I point my browser to www.mydomain.com it should be redirected to ip 0.0.0.0 (Dockers default IP on OSX), and my containerized web app should appear.

**Actual behaviour:**
The browser shows a "Failed to open page" error message.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you docker-for-mac ip ist not 0.0.0.0 - nothing has this ip. Use 127.0.0.1 if you are using docker-for-mac.

Also ensure, when you start docker, that you export the ports to the host, either by docker-compose or by docker run adding `-p 80:80` when starting your web-container

Comment: Im not using docker-for-mac, but Docker native for OSX which is normally accessed using IP 0.0.0.0. Ive tested with 127.0.0.1, and its not working. Any other idea of which IP is the correct one?

Comment: please link the project you are using, i have never hear anything about "docker native for OSX" - docker cannot be run native under osx. Its either virtualbox based, fusion, paralells or xhyve. Maybe it is called dockertoolbox?

Comment: Im sorry, I made a mistake. I am using docker-for-mac beta, but 127.0.0.1 is not working. Im trying to figure out how I can determine the docker-for-mac ip.

Answer (score 1):

see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2509

the address you specified is inaddr_any , which is basically a wildcard. so your problem is with the /etc/hosts file -  bind the domain name to a real ip of the host, e. g.  127.0.0.1